# mysql setting variable innodb_flush_method to O_DSYNC or O_DIRECT

Tags: mysql, innodb, my.cnf

In my configuration `innodb_flush_method=O_DSYNC` from `O-DIRECT` reduces about 75% the iowait, and accordingly this the load. Should I set another variables besides innodb_flush_method to reduce more the iowait?

My configuration file is:

```
[mysqld]
innodb_file_per_table=1
query_cache_size=128M
thread_cache_size=64
key_buffer_size=32M
max_allowed_packet=16M
table_cache=1024
table_definition_cache=8192
wait_timeout=20
max_user_connections=25
innodb_flush_method=O_DSYNC
open_files_limit=16384

myisam_sort_buffer_size=2M

collation_server=utf8_unicode_ci
character_set_server=utf8

tmp_table_size = 384M
max_heap_table_size = 384M
innodb_buffer_pool_size=64M
innodb_thread_concurrency=8
max_connections=125
```

I have a database with 100 Innodb tables, 3 of them has about 25000 records, the others has no significant records. The average queries in peak time is about 160, the majority is `SELECT`

Answer (score 7):

### innodb_buffer_pool_size

Major problem is `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is too small. Recommandation is set to 50~75% of main memory.

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=64M
```

I strongly recommand that you should increase it's value.

Generally speaking, `O_DIRECT` is little bit fast because InnoDB Buffer Pool caches Data+Index, So with `O_DIRECT` disabled File System Page Cache is faster. MySQL Manaual says
( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_flush_method)

> Depending on hardware configuration, setting innodb_flush_method to O_DIRECT can either have either a positive or negative effect on performance. Benchmark your particular configuration to decide which setting to use.

But in my experience, there was no significant difference between O_DIRECT and O_DSYNC. Both SSD and HDD are test.

**Anyway** you should increase `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.

#### Calculating innodb buffer pool hit ratio

```
mysql> SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%innodb%';
+---------------------------------------+-------------+
| Variable_name                         | Value       |
+---------------------------------------+-------------+
.....
.....
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests      | 11054273949 |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_reads              | 135237      |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_wait_free          | 0           |
....

innodb buffer pool hit ratio = ((Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests) / (Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests + Innodb_buffer_pool_reads)) * 100
```

E.g. above examples,

```
hit ratio = (11054273949  / (11054273949  + 135237)) * 100 = 99.99%
```

I think this value is too small in your case.

### query_cache_size

> *"the majority is SELECT"*

If most queries are SELECT and update query is rare, I think increasing `query_cache_size` is very helpful for you.

Could you post your `query cache status` as follows?

```
mysql> show global status like 'Qc%';
+-------------------------+------------+
| Variable_name           | Value      |
+-------------------------+------------+
| Qcache_free_blocks      | 13         |
| Qcache_free_memory      | 1073403104 |
| Qcache_hits             | 217949     |
| Qcache_inserts          | 337009     |
| Qcache_lowmem_prunes    | 0          |
| Qcache_not_cached       | 2122598    |
| Qcache_queries_in_cache | 68         |
| Qcache_total_blocks     | 167        |
+-------------------------+------------+

mysql> show global status like 'com_select%';
+---------------+---------+
| Variable_name | Value   |
+---------------+---------+
| Com_select    | 3292531 |
+---------------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

#### Calculating innodb buffer pool hit ratio

```
 query cache hit ratio = ((Qcache_hits) / (Qcache_hits + Com_select)) * 100
```

first, figure out your query cache hit ratio.

Comment: I have web server and mysql server on the same gear with 4GB of RAM. What do you think, what would be the optimal innodb_buffer_pool_size for me?

Comment: @zsola3075457 depends on your service environment. But mysql server mainly MySQL only. I think 2.5~3GB is sufficient. I think you need to change it from current 64M to 3GB by 1GB. ;-)

Comment: `Variable_name  Value  
Qcache_free_blocks  86
Qcache_free_memory  133448352
Qcache_hits          89537
Qcache_inserts          41561
Qcache_lowmem_prunes  0
Qcache_not_cached  386
Qcache_queries_in_cache 382
Qcache_total_blocks  881`

and

`Variable_name  Value  
Com_select  43925`

Comment: @zsola3075457 Why don't you post on you orig. question? for readability and other people can help you.

Comment: @zsola3075457 At this time, I guess your MySQL didn't received enough queries. (uptime?) so currently there are much free memories in query cache. and QC Hit ratio is approximately 60% good.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I'm new here. I have calculated the query cache hit ratio, and it is 83.22

Comment: @zsola3075457 Welcome to SO ;-) 83% is very high. So I think higher `query_cache_size` is better for you. But, first of all, `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is most important to increase performance.

Comment: I read a lot of optimal number of  'innodb_buffer_pool_size' and people say it must be larger with 10% than the data_length+index_length, what is 60M in my case. Accordyngly this the optimal size of the buffer is about 66M im my case. What do you think about this? Thank you.

Comment: @zsola3075457 I agree with you. The best scenario is entire DATA + INDEX fit in Main Memory. I should have asked your DB size. Let's move to your question. *"innodb_flush_method=O_DSYNC from O-DIRECT reduces about 75% the iowait"* this can happen when MySQL started and innodb buffer is empty. But I guess there is no difference when all data and index is loaded into buffer. Could you explain in detail about your iowait If you still doubt?

Comment: Converting `InnoDB` tables to `MyIsam`, produced another 25-40% of IO save. In my case I think the problem is that InnoDB writes to much and to often to disk (flushes like datas and logs and so on). I have `ext4` filesystem with journaling. I have tried to tune up the InnoDB by adjusting some params to the optimal values, but no succes, the mysql process writes the same. The only thing was the `innodb_flush_method` what produced a significant iowait reduction. What is, if I turn off the ext4 journaling, what produces about 30-50% of iowait, with `InnoDB` storage engine?

Comment: @zsola3075457 sorry. I think http://dba.stackexchange.com/ is the right place for you. I hope DBA would help you soon.